# MySQL query: work out the average rating for each user then order the results by average rating and number of ratings

Tags: sql, mysql

```
SELECT username, (SUM(rating)/count(*)) as TheAverage, count(*) as TheCount 
FROM ratings 
WHERE month ='Aug' AND TheCount > 1 
GROUP BY username 
ORDER BY TheAverage DESC, TheCount DESC
```

I know that's really close (I think) but it's saying 'TheCount' doesn't exist in the WHERE clause and the ORDER clause.

The table is:

id, username, rating, month

And I'm trying to work out the average rating for each user then order the results by average rating and number of ratings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you group and count, you need having:

```
SELECT username, (SUM(rating)/COUNT(*)) as TheAverage, Count(*) as TheCount
    FROM rating
    WHERE month='Aug'
    GROUP BY username
    HAVING TheCount > 1
    ORDER BY TheAverage DESC, TheCount DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT username, (SUM(rating)/count()) as TheAverage, count() as TheCount 
FROM ratings 
WHERE month ='Aug'
GROUP BY username
HAVING TheCount > 1
ORDER BY TheAverage DESC, TheCount DESC
```

**EDIT:**

Seems I didn't look closely enough.

I think it'll work now.

Comment: You just used `TheAverage`, which is an alias, in the order by clause.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work. Has a problem with the count()

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `AVG` aggregate:

```
SELECT  username, month, AVG(rating) as TheAverage, COUNT(*) as TheCount
FROM    ratings
WHERE   month ='Aug'
GROUP BY
        username
HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY
        TheAverage DESC, TheCount DESC
```

Grouping by `month` is innesessary in `MySQL`, since your `month` is filtered and `MySQL` supports selecting an ungrouped column in a `SELECT` list of a `GROUP BY` query (returning a random value within the group).